# Filter Rails 3 module using dynamic filters that are based on aggregates

Tags: filter, ruby-on-rails-3, aggregate

I have a model that includes attributes like company_name, posted (a date), location (lat/lng pair).  In the Index view, I segment the result set using the will_paginate gem.

I would like to include dynamic filters that are based on the query's results.  For example, if an aging bucket is chosen, the other filters would be based on this restriction.  Ideally, I would be able to sort some of the value by frequency.  Something like:

```
Posted: [ 0 (24) | 30 (51) | 60 (45) | 90+ (555) ]
Company: [ Company X (53) | Company AAA (44) | ... ] 
Locations: [ New York (100) | Paris (51) | ... ]
```

I thought about using a helper function to calculate the aggregates based on the result's collection, but the will_paginate gem's collection (e.g. @foos) only includes the current page's result.  Perhaps there is a way to access the entire result set.

I suppose I could execute a series of SQL statements to calculate each filter's frequency values, but I was hoping there might be a more-efficient way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had some success with the following approach:

controller:

```
...
# WHERE clause
@foos = @foos.posted(params[:posted]) if params[:posted].present?

# clone recordset
@companies = @foos.clone

# set ORDER BY / pagination
@foos = @foos.order_by(params[:sort], params[:dir]).paginate(:per_page => Foo.per_page, :page => params[:page])
...
```

view:

```
...
Company: [
<% @companies.group_by(&:company_name).sort.each do |company, foos| %>
    <%= "#company.name} (#{foos.length})" %> | 
<% end %>
]
...
```

Perhaps there is a DRYer/more-efficient way to do this.